# Return the condition in the fitler?

Tags: f#

I have the following code to filter a `Seq` and return the error if nothing returned.

```
let s = nodes
        |> Seq.filter(fun (a, _, _, _) -> if a.ToLower().Contains(key1)) // condition 1
                                          then true
                                          else false // Error message should have Key1
        |> Seq.filter(....) // condition 2
        |> Seq.filter(....) // condition 3
        ..... 
        |> Seq.filter(function // condition N
           | _, Some date, _, _ -> date >= StartPeriod 
           | _ -> false // put StartPeriod in the final message s is not empty before this step
           )

if Seq.isEmpty s
then sprintf "Failed by condition 1 (%s) or condition 2 (%s) .... or condition N (Date > %s)" 
               key1, ...., (StartPeriod.ToShortDateSTring())
else ....
```

The final error message `sprintf` will contain all the filter conditions. Is it a way to let the code just return the ones (or just the last one) make the `s` empty?

---

Based on rmunn's answer, I modified it to return all the filters that contributed to empty the list.

```
let rec filterSeq filterList input msgs =
    match filterList with
    | [] -> input, msgs
    | (label, filter) :: filters ->
        let result = input |> Seq.filter filter
        if result |> Seq.isEmpty then
            printfn "The \"%s\" filter emptied out the input" label
            Seq.empty, (List.append msgs [label])
        else
            filterSeq filters result (List.append msgs [label])

let intFiltersWithLabels = [
    "Odd numbers", fun x -> x % 2 <> 0
    "Not divisible by 3", fun x -> x % 3 <> 0
    "Not divisible by 5", fun x -> x % 5 <> 0
    "Even numbers", fun x -> x % 2 = 0
    "Won't reach here", fun x -> x % 7 <> 0
]

{ 1..20 } |> filterSeq intFiltersWithLabels <| List.empty
```

Comment: The very last sentence of the question does not make sense. I read it through multiple times, but was unable to understand what it meant. Can you please try to rephrase the question?

Comment: The filter may graduately remove some elements. When the s is empty, I want the error message show the one filter (or all files before the one) makes s from non empty to empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is make a list of filters, and a recursive function that applies them one at a time. If the filter that was just applied returns an empty sequence, then stop, print the filter that just emptied your input, and return that empty sequence. Otherwise keep looping through the recursive function, taking the *next* filter in the list in turn, until either you end up with no input or you have run through your entire filter list and there's still some input remaining after passing all the filters.

Here's some sample code to illustrate what I mean. Notice how I've put labels in front of each filter function, so that I don't see output like "The `<fun:filtersWithLabels@4>` filter emptied out the input", but instead I see a sensible human-readable label for each filter.

```
let rec filterSeq filterList input =
    match filterList with
    | [] -> input
    | (label, filter) :: filters ->
        let result = input |> Seq.filter filter
        if result |> Seq.isEmpty then
            printfn "The \"%s\" filter emptied out the input" label
            Seq.empty
        else
            filterSeq filters result

let intFiltersWithLabels = [
    "Odd numbers", fun x -> x % 2 <> 0
    "Not divisible by 3", fun x -> x % 3 <> 0
    "Not divisible by 5", fun x -> x % 5 <> 0
    "Even numbers", fun x -> x % 2 = 0
    "Won't reach here", fun x -> x % 7 <> 0
]

{ 1..20 } |> filterSeq filtersWithLabels
// Prints: The "Even numbers" filter emptied out the input
```

If you want to print *all* filters until the one that emptied out the input, then you'd just move that printfn call up one line, outside the `if` expression. The fact that the recursion stops once the input is empty means that you won't see any printfn calls after the filter that emptied out the input.

Note that the way I wrote the function assumes that your original input will not be empty. If your original input was empty, then the function will credit the first filter for emptying the input and will print the first filter's label. You could solve that easily enough by checking for empty input before you check for empty result, but I didn't bother since this is just demo code. Just be aware of this if your real input could ever be empty in your actual use case.

**Update:** If you need to return a list of labels, not just print them, then make that a second parameter that you pass through your `filterSeq` function. Something like this:

```
let matchingFilters filterList input =
    let rec filterSeq filterList labelsSoFar input =
        match filterList with
        | [] -> input, []  // Note NO labels returned in this case!
        | (label, filter) :: filters ->
            let result = input |> Seq.filter filter
            if result |> Seq.isEmpty then
                Seq.empty, (label :: labelsSoFar)
            else
                filterSeq filters (label :: labelsSoFar) result
    let result, labels = filterSeq filterList [] input
    result, List.rev labels

let filtersWithLabels = [
    "Odd numbers", fun x -> x % 2 <> 0
    "Not divisible by 3", fun x -> x % 3 <> 0
    "Not divisible by 5", fun x -> x % 5 <> 0
    "Even numbers", fun x -> x % 2 = 0
    "Won't reach here", fun x -> x % 7 <> 0
]

{ 1..20 } |> matchingFilters filtersWithLabels
// Returns: ["Odd numbers"; "Not divisible by 3"; "Not divisible by 5"; "Even numbers"]
```

A couple things to note about this version of the function: it sounds like what you want is that if the filters run all the way through without emptying out the input, then you want NO filter labels to be returned. If I've misunderstood you, then replace the `| [] -> input, []` line with `| [] -> input, labelsSoFar` to get *all* the labels in the output. Second thing to note is that I've changed the "shape" of this function: instead of returning a seq, it returns a 2-tuple of (result seq, list of filter labels). The list of filter labels will be empty if the result seq is not empty, but if the result seq ended up empty, then the list of filter labels will contain *all the filters that were applied*, not just all the filters that reduced the size of the input.

If what you really need is to check whether the size of the input is reduced and print *only* the labels of filters that filtered something out, then look at Funk's answer for how to check that, but be aware that `Seq.length` has to run through the entire *original sequence* and apply all the filters up to that point, *each time*. So it's a slow operation. If your input data set is large, then it's best to stick with the `Seq.empty` logic. Play around with it and decide what best fits your needs.

Comment: Funny, your solution definitely looks more functional :) though composing with other higher order functions seems tricky.

Comment: If you might need other types of higher order functions (say you need `Seq.filter` and `Seq.map`) then change what's in the list. Instead of the list containing filters, make it contain "steps", where a step is a `seq<'a> -> seq<'a>` function: `Seq.filter (fun x -> x % 2 <> 0)` would be a step, and `Seq.map (fun x -> x + 1)` would also be a step. Then instead of `let result = input |> Seq.filter filter`, you'd do `let result = input |> step`.

Comment: Sure, but you would be adding unnecessary complexity and losing flexibility. For example, you would be checking Seq.isEmpty after Seq.map. Or alternatively, adding more complexity singling that out...

Comment: @Funk - Your solution is also a good one: a simple logging wrapper is a very useful tool to keep in one's toolbox. And BTW, wrapping a function around another one is also very functional, so don't feel like your answer was "less functional" than mine.

Comment: What if I need to get all the messages of the filters that emptied the input? In your example, the messages will be `["Odd numbers"; "Not divisible by 3"; "Not divisible by 5", "Even numbers"]`.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - See the next-to-last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: I've edited the question with a solution (based on your solution) to return all the filters empty the list.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - You were just a tiny bit too fast in editing your question. See my updated answer.

Comment: Your code is better (no need to pass `[]` for the initial label list). You use `label :: labelsSoFar` and then `List.rev labels`. How it compares with `List.append labelsSoFar [label]` only?

Comment: Using `List.append labelsSoFar [label]` is O(N) since F# lists are singly-linked lists, and you'd need to do it N times so that's O(N^2) total. Appending to the head of an F# list is O(1) and you do it N times, so that's O(N) total. Then because you've been appending to the head as you go, the list is most-recent-first and you want least-recent-first, so you do a final `List.rev` (an O(N) operation) once. So the way I did it is O(N), and the `List.append` approach you're asking about would be O(N^2); that's the difference.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrsmith/2008/07/10/mastering-f-lists/ for more about F# lists and why you should work at the head of the list, not the tail, as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate your logging / error handling code from your business logic by using a decorator.

First, our logger.

```
open System.Text

type Logger() =
    let sb = StringBuilder()
    member __.log msg =
        sprintf "Element doesn't contain %s ; " msg |> sb.Append |> ignore
    member __.getMessage() =
        sb.ToString()
```

Now, we want to wrap `Seq.filter` so it logs every time we filter out some element(s).

```
let filterBuilder (logger:Logger) msg f seq = 
    let res = Seq.filter f seq
    if Seq.length seq > Seq.length res then logger.log msg
    res
```

Wrapping up with an example.

```
let logger = Logger()
let filterLog msg f seq = filterBuilder logger msg f seq 

let seq = ["foo" ; "bar"]

let r =
    seq 
    |> filterLog "f"
        (fun s -> s.Contains("f")) 
    |> filterLog "o"
        (fun s -> s.Contains("o")) 
    |> filterLog "b"
        (fun s -> s.Contains("b")) 
    |> filterLog "a"
        (fun s -> s.Contains("a")) 

logger.getMessage()
```

> val it : string = "Element doesn't contain f ; Element doesn't contain b ; "

`"bar"` gets filtered out immediately, producing the first message. `"foo"` goes out the third time around. Also note the second and last pipe in the line don't log any message.

Comment: I like the wrapping-a-function-around-the-work-function approach. The one thing I'm not a fan of here is the repeated use of `Seq.length`, which is doing two extra O(N) operations at each step. That's going to slow things down more than needed; the OP's particular use case just needs to know if the seq became empty, and `Seq.isEmpty` is O(1) since it only needs to check whether the seq has at least one item in it.